# Bs datepicker's value updates but display value does not update

Tags: angularjs, typescript, razor, datepicker

The version of angularjs is 1.5.11.

I am using the bs-datepicker element from angularjs in my .NET MVC project. Here is my datepicker and a couple images used as buttons in my app:

```
<input class="form-control"
                       type="text"
                       placeholder="Pick a Date (default today)."
                       data-date-format="MM-dd-yyyy"
                       data-min-date="today"
                       bs-datepicker
                       data-autoclose="true"
                       ng-model="tos.appointmentDay"
                       ng-change="tos.updateAppointments()"
                       style="width: 100px;" />
<div class="appointment-buttons">
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-lg"
                             ng-click="tos.decrementAppointmentDate()" />
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-lg"
                             ng-click="tos.incrementAppointmentDate()" />
                    </div>
```

I have the two arrow image elements being use as buttons to change the day forward or backward one day in my appointment app. The buttons do change the date correctly along with this datepicker (by using my functions in my controller) and I can see it being reflected in both the datepicker popup and other text output I have in my code to display the date.

However, when I update the value of the appointmentDay property in my app through the two arrow buttons, all of my outputs update, including the actual value of the datepicker, but the display value in the text input field of the datepicker does not update. Why will the datepicker's value in the popup update correctly, but the text input field for the bs-datepicker not update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that when you perform a setDate call in JavaScript/TypeScript on a date object bound to an element (a datepicker in this case), it would not update the datapicker. This is because you need to explicitly assign objects you have bound to an element to change their values. This was true for the bs-datepicker element and true for angularjs.

You should:

```
//Do this.
var temp = original;
temp.setDate(newDate);
original = temp;

//Don't do this by itself.
original.setDate(newDate);
```